# If $G$ doesn't contain a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$ induced subgraph, then $G$ is planar

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> How can I prove that if $G$ doesn't contain a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$
>   subgraph, then $G$ is planar? Or is this statement false?

I'm aware of Kuratowski's Theorem, which states that $G$ is nonplanar if and only if $G$ contains a subgraph that is a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$.  I'm not sure if I can go from here to the result that I'd like to prove. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You might want to check the differences between subgraphs and minors.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is false.

Consider the graph $G$ that is $K_5$, but each edge has had  a vertex added in the middle. [So it has $5$ vertices of degree $4$ and $10$ vertices of  degree $2$. It is of course a subdivision of $K_5$.] This graph is not planar---if we had a planar drawing then just erasing the vertices of degree $2$ would give us a planar drawing of $K_5$ (which is impossible). On the other hand $G$ contains no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subgraph.

Comment: Why is $K_5$ not an induced subgraph of the constructed graph? I thought induced subgraph means choosing subset of vertices and connecting the edges between these vertices that are in the original graph. So why can't I just choose the $5$ vertices of degree $4$ as my induced subgraph? And the result will be $K_5$?

Comment: @hom The $5$ vertices of  degree $4$ are only joined to vertices of degree $2$, so the induced subgraph of $G$ containing those $4$ vertices has no edges at all; very far from a $K_5$.